# concatenate string and integer and call existing variable

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

var1 = 123

var2 = 234

Is there a way to concatenate 'var' + '1' with the resulting string used to call/reference to the existing variable var1?

For example: (this doesn't work)
print(('var'+'1')) would yield: 123

Thanks.

Comment: that is why you have dict in python, you could create a new dict with `dict = {}` and populate it with `var1` and `var2` like `dict['var1'] = 123` and `dict['var2']=234` and you could perform operations like `print(dict['var'+str(1)])`

Comment: ok, thanks, noted on this being doable within a dict... question remains if this can be done with an assigned variable???

Comment: I have not yet seen someone do it, so I doubt it is possible, but there are lots of python experts on here so someone might be able to help you. It will just get very compicated I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

found an answer to my own question with the `eval()` function...

```
var1 = 123
var2 = 234
```

for this example, `print(eval('var1'))` will yield: `123`

Comment: Try to avoid using `eval`: if you `print(eval(input()))`, a malicious user could enter "print('blahblah')" or something and it'll evaluate the script.